# VS2015 doesn't remember this setting

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[image]

I check Show All Files but the next time I open VS it's unchecked.

Comment: It can't remember a selection and you randomly *delete* files and registry keys?  Step away from the keyboard slowly, Lord knows what kind of damage you did.  This selection is normally stored in the hidden .suo file in the solution directory.  Extra hidden in VS2015 to reduce the odds that it gets randomly deleted or overwritten, .vs/solutionname/v14 subdirectory.

Comment: Deleting the `.suo` solved my problem (I took a backup). About the deletion of files, I did that between un-install and re-install of VS. If you post a separate answer I'll mark it as solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selection is based on the project where it is clicked and saved locally to the projects `.suo` file. It is not *global* for every project/solution.

Once set for a target project, verify the setting after one closes, then opens the *same* project/solution for a new session.